# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.getContext()' on a null object reference

Tags: cordova, ionic2, google-plus

I'm using Ionic 2 for my android application.

Whenever I try to login with the Cordova Google Plus plugin, it returns the following error:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context
>   com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.getContext()' on a
>   null object reference

I'm testing on a real device (Android 5) with Google+ installed and activated.

```
 GooglePlus.login().then((data) => {
  console.log(data);
}).catch((data) => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

in this way it should work:

```
 GooglePlus.login({}).then((data) => {
  console.log(data);
}).catch((data) => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Great! Thank you. This should be approved!